# Why is my attempt to mock out an @Spy ObjectMapper resulting in an NPE?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the following declaration:

```
@Spy ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

For most of my tests, this works as expected, `mapper` behaves as per its defaults. In one of my tests, I mock out `ObjectMapper::writeValueAsBytes` and that works fine as well. But the following fails:

```
when(mapper.readValue(any(byte[].class), eq(ProfileCacheReply.class)))
    .thenThrow(IOException.class);
```

With the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:839)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2807)
at com.org.loaders.ProfileCacheLoaderTest.sendRequestThrewExceptionDeserializingProfileCacheResponse(ProfileCacheLoaderTest.java:174)
```

I see that in the `readValue` method, `JsonFactory::createParser` is in fact called, but shouldn't `@Spy` handle this by resorting to the default behavior of `ObjectMapper`? And furthermore, since I am stubbing out this method, why does it actually care about the original implementation?

EDIT:

This is how the method is used in the tested class, however, note that I don't actually invoke this method in my test! The exception occurs when I try to set my mock up using `when()`

```
try {
  profileCacheReply = mapper.readValue(responseByteString.toByteArray(), ProfileCacheReply.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to deserialize ProfileCacheReply", e);
}
```

Comment: Could you post how readValue method is called in code?

Comment: Added; however, note that I never make it as far as testing the method. The exception is thrown during `when()`

Comment: try this way: doThrow(IOException.class).when(mapper).readValue(any(byte[].class), eq(ProfileCacheReply.class))

Comment: That worked; can you please answer with an explanation of why my code was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this would answer your query: http://www.stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito. If you are fine with solution then you can accept answer :)

Comment: Ahh this will save me some hours of frustration going forward